# How to use Microsoft Graph API from the front end on a non SPFx application?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is there is a way of achieving this? what steps would I need to follow?

Comment: The ones that downvoted the questions are the reason why so many people have move away from this platform, they don't help or even give a reason on why the question does not satisfied there "high standards"

Answer (score 1):

MS Graph API is a Rest API which does not rely on any paltform. Of course you can use it on a non-spfx application.

We suggest you walk through the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), it has a lot of [samples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-community-samples), you can get started with the [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials?view=graph-rest-1.0). And it offers a smart [tool for interacting with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api?view=graph-rest-1.0#graph-explorer)

BR